# Views exposed Filter does not appear to work

Tags: views

I have a view set for a content type 'Organization' containing a field 'specno'.  The field contains a five character ID number for classifying the 'Organization' content. The exposed filter is set to "is equal to" and I enter a value of '033000' in the exposed filter box.  The query generated for the view is

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_specno} field_data_field_specno ON node.nid = field_data_field_specno.entity_id AND (field_data_field_specno.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_specno.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('organization')) AND (field_data_field_specno.field_specno_value LIKE '033000' ESCAPE '\\') ))
ORDER BY node_title DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

however, the display result does not contain the appropriate content. I have tried changing the filter to "Contains" and 'Starts with", but without success for nothing is displayed in the preview.

I am using D7 & V3.  Does anyone have any insight as to why this is not working?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't contain only the numbers, maybe some html as well. Give contains a try to see if it's the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but looking directly at the database field, the test value is present and there HTML is not included.

Comment: what do you get when you run that query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: It can come from Drupal as well, I had same problem with date field.